# Unable to get or delete data from sharepoint list with more than 5000 records using Shareplum

Tags: sharepoint-list

I am trying to get sharepoint list items to pandas dataframe using Shareplum. But due to threshold limit I am unable to get the list items. Attaching the screenshot below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klqH8.png)